# Should i create struct for every core data entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

```
public class ApiEntity: NSManagedObject {

}

extension ApiEntity {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ApiEntity> {
        return NSFetchRequest<ApiEntity>(entityName: "ApiEntity")
    }

    @NSManaged public var paths: String?
    @NSManaged public var value: String?
    @NSManaged public var watch: Bool
    @NSManaged public var watchValue: String?
    @NSManaged public var endPoint: EndPointEntity?

}
```

Core data entity is like this. Because it's a class, so when i use it with SwiftUI, i must refresh view manually every time the property changes.

#### My question is

Should create an corresponding struct like

```
struct ApiEntityStruct {
   public var paths: String?
}
```

for every entity and convert to struct when reading and back to class when writing ?

## Edit

Seems like NSManagedObject conforms to ObjectObservable. So if it declared by @ObservedObject, it should work.

Comment: This is a good start: https://blckbirds.com/post/core-data-and-swiftui/#
As official document says, NSManagedObject conforms to ObjectObservable, I think you can update your view easily whenever an entity is changed without creating extra Structs.

Comment: But i found only the fields decorate with @Published can refresh view. But the field in NSManagedObject even not decorate with it also can refresh view.

Comment: So do you need structs for SwiftUI or not?